# Why is it e and why is it raised to a negative power?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, eulers-number-e

Why is $(1-\frac{1}{m})^{kn} \approx e^{-kn/m}$? I mean, when do we know when $e$ should be raised to a negative exponent? and how do we even know it's e?

Little background info:
We have a bit vector of size $m$, $n$ elements, $k$ hash functions, and $\frac{1}{m}$ is the probability that a specific bit is flipped to $1$ (assuming independence at perfect randomness). The above equation is for a Bloom filter. It tells us the probability that a specific bit in the bit vector (size=$m$), after inserting $n$ element with $k$ hash functions, is still $0$. It makes sense, that it should approach $0$ and that it wouldn't make sense if it was raised to a non-negative power, but I still need to know how mathematicians come up with such conclusions? And how to they even know it is e?

SOURCE: scribe notes from CS 6550 – Design and Analysis of Algorithms, Dana Randall on Bloom Filters.

Comment: The equation you wrote in the first line is wrong.

Comment: it's wrong? it's taken directly out of a paper. How do you mean?

Comment: $(1-\frac 1 m)^{kn}=e^{kn \ln (1-\frac 1 m)}$.

Comment: read the scribe notes on Design and Analysis of Algorithms by Dana Randall on Bloom Filters if you are in doubt. Thanks for the downvote :-)

Comment: What happens if you put $m=1$?

Comment: It is regrettable that the authors do not know what equality in Mathematics means.

Comment: I looked at the notes you mentioned, and the notes are wrong: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~randall/AlgsF09/bloomfilters.pdf It could be fixed just by replacing the equal sign with an approximately equal sign, though. It helps to know that $(1 + \frac{1}{x})^x \approx e$ when $x$ is large.

Comment: Classical issue with "engineering mathematics": it's hardly ever rigorous.

Comment: @littleO, would it still be e even though the parenthesis is not raised to the same variable as in the denominator? i.e. $m$ is not $n$: $(1-\frac{1}{m})^{kn}$

Comment: Jeff Erickson, also states the same. However is not equal to but approximately.

Comment: $(1-\frac{1}{m})^{kn} = (1+\frac{-1}{m})^{m\frac{kn}m} \approx e^{-1\cdot \frac{kn}m}$ for large enough $m$.

Comment: The approximation I mentioned tells us that $(1 - \frac{1}{m})^{-m} \approx e$. Now, if we raise both sides to the power of $-kn/m$, we obtain $(1 - \frac{1}{m})^{kn} \approx e^{-kn/m}$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis how do you move m out of the equation and raise it to m and also multiply by $\frac{kn}{m}$?

Comment: @littleO interesting. Are we allowed to make such assumptions about $m$? And how  are we allowed to just raise to the power of $\frac{-kn}{m}$? It seems like magic for me

Comment: I just rewrote the exponent: $kn=1\cdot kn = \frac{m}{m}\cdot kn = m \cdot \frac{kn}{m}$. In the next step I also made use of the fact that $(a^b)^c = a^{b\cdot c}$.

Comment: An equation says that two things are equal. In this case the two things are expressions representing some number. If you do a calculation with a number as input, and you then repeat that same calculation with the same number as input, the result will be the same. Here you have an equation saying that you have the same number on the left hand side as you have on the right hand side. On both sides you do the same calculation (raising it to the power $-\frac{kn}{m}$), so the two results will have to be the same.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis For $m\to\infty$ I think that  $1-\frac{k n}{m}$  describes in a simpler and more effective way the situation

Comment: But to make the assumption that $m$ goes to infinity makes no sense for me, since $m$ is the length of the bit vector. Don't you agree? Wouldn't the assumption that $n\rightarrow \infty$ make more sense, since $n$ is number of elements that hashes to the bit vector?

Answer (score 1):

Let m be a positive integer having nothing to do with your question. By binomial expansion, $$(1-\dfrac1m)^m=1-m(\dfrac1m)+\dfrac{m(m-1)}2(\dfrac1m)^2-\dfrac{m(m-1)(m-2)}6(\dfrac1m)^3+...+(-1)^m\dfrac{m!}{m!}(\dfrac1m)^m$$ Each term may written as $(-1)^k\dfrac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-k+1)}{k!}(\dfrac1m)^k$, so if we let $m\to\infty$, the expression becomes $$1-1+\dfrac12-\dfrac16+...+(-1)^m\dfrac1{m!}$$

Let the j-th term be $t_j$, then $|t_j|$ decreases monotinally and $\lim_{j\to\infty}t_j=0$. Therefore, by the altering series test, $1-1+\dfrac12-\dfrac16+...+(-1)^m\dfrac1{m!}$ converges. In fact, the series formed by $|t_j|$ is $$(1+\dfrac1m)^m=1+m(\dfrac1m)+\dfrac{m(m-1)}2(\dfrac1m)^2+\dfrac{m(m-1)(m-2)}6(\dfrac1m)^3+...+\dfrac{m!}{m!}(\dfrac1m)^m,$$ letting $m\to\infty$, this expression tends to $e$. Notice that $$(1-\dfrac1m)^m(1+\dfrac1m)^m=(1-\dfrac1{m^2})^m=\sum_{j=0}^m(-1)^j\dfrac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-j+1)}{j!}(\dfrac1m)^{j}(\dfrac1m)^{j},$$ which tends to $1$ as $m\to\infty$. Hence $\lim_{t\to\infty}(1-\dfrac1m)^m=\dfrac1e$. By the definition of the limit, this means that for any real number $\varepsilon\gt 0$, there exist a positive integer $N$ such that $|(1-\dfrac1m)^m-\dfrac1e|\lt\varepsilon$ whenever $m\ge N.$ In other words, if $m$ is a sufficiently large (finite) positive integer, we have $(1-\dfrac1m)^m\approx\dfrac1e$. Now that $m$ is finite, we can associate it to your question by letting $m$ be the size of your vector (taken from the background info you provided for your question).

Therefore, $(1-\dfrac1m)^{kn}=((1-\dfrac1m)^m)^{kn/m}\approx (\dfrac1e)^{kn/m}=e^{-kn/m}.$